# OBD-II Simulator on OS-X

Tags: macos, bluetooth, obd-ii

Has somebody installed OBD-II simulator on mac? I tried downloading it from this site - http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html for OS-X.

After installation and opening ObdGPSLogger, I can see GPS logger window and different parameter gauges. However, after selecting Logfile, and device there is nothing happening.

In the Raw output, below is the error displayed under StdErr:

```
Dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/chunky/gpsd//lib/libgps.18.dylib
 Referenced from: /Applications/OBD GPS Logger.app/Contents/Resources/bin/obdgpslogger
 Reason: image not found
```

Let me know if you guys know the cause

Comment: Do you have `/Users/chunky/gpsd//lib/libgps.18.dylib` on your system?  If so, try `file /Users/chunky/gpsd//lib/libgps.18.dylib` to see whether it has the right type.

Comment: You should run ObdSim, it's another package inside the thing you downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here, but I got it working on a Mac downloading the **obdgpslogger-0.16.tar.gz**  version (in the Tarball section) from [this link](http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/).

You need to navigate to the downloaded folder and then run the commands:

- mkdir build
- cd build
- cmake ..
- make
- make install # optional

Comment: what is meant by `cmake ..`? What to write instead of the dots?

Comment: @jux_97 that's the exact command. Check the section "Building" in http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/